# How to cater empty values in Grok Pattern Logstash

Tags: wso2, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration, wso2-esb

I have following log entry that I want to parse using the GROK pattern via Logstash.

**Log Entry:**

```
1. TID: [-1234] [ESB] 
2. TID: [-1234] []
```

Following is my grok pattern which is also working fine on Log entry 1 :

```
TID:%{SPACE}\[%{INT:SourceSystemId}\]%{SPACE}\[%{WORD:server_type}\]
```

But I want the expression that works on both the log entry 1 and 2. It should also cater the empty values and does not fail. I am using [this website](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/) to test my grok patterns.

**Problem:**

The problem is that "WORD" pattern does not cater for empty space or no alphabet, and I cannot write custom pattern .

```
WORD \b\w+\b
```

I tried to write inline regex to solve this but I am not able to get it working. can somebody please guide me that how to use inline regex for this particular case in GROK patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change `WORD` to `DATA` and it will work:

```
TID:%{SPACE}\[%{INT:SourceSystemId}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:server_type}\]
                                                  ^
                                                  |
                                             change this
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the (pattern)? character to mark zero or one occurences:

```
TID:%{SPACE}\[%{INT:SourceSystemId}\]%{SPACE}\[(%{WORD:server_type})?\]
```

Credit to magnusbaeck from elastic community. [link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/making-a-part-in-the-grok-expression-optional/43961)

Comment: Worked like a charm!!!! The link provides very good insight